GRPC bidirectional stream content is not getting transferred from GRPC Cient to GRPC Server via Ingress Nginx Controller
Problem Details - GRPC bidirectional stream content is not getting transferred from GRPC cient to GRPC Server via Ingress Nginx  Controller unless on clomplete is invoked by GRPC client.
Usecase  - Message communication between GRPC client and GRPC server over a long lived  bidirectional GRPC stream  through Ingress Nginx Controller.
 GRPC Client    ->  Ingress Nginx  Controller   ->  GRPC Server
Proto
service TestService {
rpc HealthBidirectional (stream HealthRequest) returns (stream HealthResponse) {}
}
message HealthRequest {
string name = 1;
}
message HealthResponse {
string message = 1;
}
private static void infiniteBiDirectional(ManagedChannel channel) {

        StreamObserver<HealthRequest> streamObserver = TestServiceGrpc.newStub(channel)
                .withInterceptors(getClientInterceptor()).healthBidirectional(new StreamObserver<HealthResponse>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(HealthResponse value) {
                        LOGGER.info("healthBidirectional " + " HEALTH RESPONSE " + value.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        LOGGER.info("healthBidirectional " + " Error" + t);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        LOGGER.info("healthBidirectional " + " Completed.");
                    }

                });

        request = HealthRequest.newBuilder().setName("00000").build();
        streamObserver.onNext(request);
        request = HealthRequest.newBuilder().setName("11111").build();
        streamObserver.onNext(request);

               // The flow work fine in case onComplete is invoked but since the usecase is about long lived streams , We require messages onNext message to be sent to server and keep the stream open for infinite time.
        // streamObserver.onCompleted();  
    }

Tried with multiple Ingress annotation configuration
  inginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: GRPC
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 4M
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    grpc_send_timeout                      360s;
    grpc_read_timeout                      360s;
    client_body_timeout                    60s;
    proxy_ignore_client_abort              on;
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 0m
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "off"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "360"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "off"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "360"

Tweaked client_body_timeout to 60 so error becomes visible after 1 minute only.
Nginx error log (HTTP 408)
10.82.151.80 - - [02/Jun/2024:18:00:22 +0000] "POST /proto.TestService/HealthBidirectional HTTP/2.0" 408 0 "-" "grpc-java-netty/1.60.0" 294 60.001 [test-system-grpc-test-5000] [] - - - - 5d4b04fb64c1bd020dcbee78e0089f4a
GRPC client error log
INFO: healthBidirectional  Errorio.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR
GRPC Server
The request is not reaching to GRPC Server.
In a nutshell the Ingress Nginx Controller is not able to determine the when the message body is ending. How can I resolve this issue?
